# Conductor - Controller Pager Adapter | Out of memory crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I recently made an app with a ViewPager and my child fragments weren't being destroyed properly causing out of memory exception. I fixed it by using this https://github.com/adamsp/FragmentStatePagerIssueExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/fragmentstatepagerissueexample/app/FixedFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java

Now I have rebuilt my app to use Controllers instead of fragments and things got messy. The Conductor library has official support of ViewPager via ControllerPagerAdapter, but it seems as broken as the original android one. Here's my code:

---

I make the adapter in PagerController:

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerViewAdapter(this, pdfFactory.getPageCount());
```

PagerViewAdapter:

```
public class PagerViewAdapter extends ControllerPagerAdapter {
private final int size;

public PagerViewAdapter(Controller controller, int size) {
    super(controller, false);
    this.size = size;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public Controller getItem(int position) {
    return new PagerImageController(position);
}

}
```

PagerImageController:

```
public class PagerImageController extends Controller {
@Inject PdfFactory pdfFactory;
private int position;

public PagerImageController() {}

public PagerImageController(int position) {
    this.position = position;
    setRetainViewMode(RetainViewMode.RELEASE_DETACH);
    Log.d("LOG", "PagerImageController: "+position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container) {
    //Dagger 2
    ((CorePdfApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);

    //Locate and inflate the PhotoView
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_element, container, false);
    PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) v.findViewById(R.id.pager_image);
    Observable.just(position)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(integer -> {
                photoView.setImageBitmap(pdfFactory.getPage(integer));
            })
            .subscribe();
    return v;
}
}
```

LOG:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
                                                                          at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:114)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20866572 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 18MB until OOM
```

Any ideas how to fix this one?